# Хэш код, расшифровка

Tags: hashcode

Как расшфровать хэш код " SHA-1 Hash/ /MySQL5 Hash "

Comment: Хэш-коды по определению не расшифровываются, так как являются сверткой. Можно только попытаться подобрать по [радужным таблицам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Comment: А откуда взят хэшкод? Возможно, есть более простой способ. Если есть определенный доступ.

Answer (score 2):

`SHA-1` это [криптографическая хэш-функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Главное требование для таких функций это необратимость.

> Необратимость или стойкость к
> восстановлению прообраза: для
> заданного значения хеш-функции m
> должно быть вычислительно невозможно
> найти блок данных X, для которого
> H(X)=m.

В теории нет различий между теорией и практикой. Но на практике всё немного не так. Для конечного множества возможных исходных сообщений (например будем считать что исходное сообщение не могло быть длиннее n байт) то можно вычислить SHA-1 для всех возможных исходных сообщений сверяя его с нашим хэшем пока они не совпадут. Вычисление хэша задача ресурсоёмкая (криптографические хэш-функции специально делают ресурсоёмкими что-бы затруднить подобную атаку) поэтому для больших значений n сложность полного перебора весьма высока (от нескольких дней на одной мощной видеокарте, до нескольких дейсятков лет на нескольких десятках мощных видеокарт, в зависимости от хэш-функции и предполагаемой длинны исходного сообщения).

В общем советую тебе поискать другой способ добиться желаемого. Или крепко подружиться с кем-то из АНБ, у них много вычислительных ресурсов заточенных под такие задачи (:

Хотя если исходное сообщение это что-то словарное (например "Qwerty-1", "gfhjkm" или хрестоматийное "sex", "love", "god") то используя атаку по словарю можно восстановить его за несколько минут или часов на обычном процессоре.